# Finding whether a sequence diverges or converges

Tags: calculus

Would the following sequence diverge or converge.

$\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{2n^4+1}}$

I did divided by $n^4$ and got

$\frac{1/n^2}{\sqrt{2+1/n^4}}$

Would this mean the sequence would converge to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you didn't divide by $n^4$ but factor ist out. I guess factoring out $n^2$ will help more.

$$\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{2n^4+1}} = \frac{n^2}{n^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^4}}}}$$

Comment: but how do you get only 2 when you factor n^2 out of 2n^4?

Comment: because you have a square root and for $n\geq 0$ it is $n^2 =\sqrt{n^4}$

Comment: oh I see that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

If you divided it by $n^4$, it would have been
$$\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^8}}}$$ which does not help. Divide it by $n^2$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{n^4}}}$$

Comment: In fact you don't divide by $n^2$ but factor it out. (You divide the nominator and the denominator). Because if you devide by $n^2$ you would get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 n^4+1}}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use comparison test

$u_n=\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{2n^4+1}}, v_n=\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^4}}=1$